# vscode phpcs: referenced sniff Universal.WhiteSpace.DisallowInlineTabs does not exist

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpcs

I have had a lot of issues setting up `phpcs` and `vscode` — they worked perfectly for a while, but then after reorganizing some folders, I moved my `wpcs` repo somewhere else. Now trying to reconfigure `phpcs` and cannot figure out what the problem is. I keep getting an error that `Universal.WhiteSpace.DisallowInlineTabs` does not exist. Here is a screenshot
[image]

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used homebrew to install `phpcs` instead of composer. Because I didn't want to switch to composer I started using `PHPCSUtils`'s  ['Non-Composer based integration'](https://github.com/PHPCSStandards/PHPCSUtils#non-composer-based-integration) but realized that I didn't want to have to manually update the package every time a new release came out.

Instead I cloned `PHPCSUtils` and `PHPCSExtras` into directories in the same parent folder as my `WPCS` directory. Then I symlinked them into the `WPCS` folder

```
git clone git@github.com:WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards.git wpcs
git clone git@github.com:PHPCSStandards/PHPCSExtra.git
git clone git@github.com:PHPCSStandards/PHPCSUtils.git
cd wpcs
ln -s ../PHPCSUtils/PHPCSUtils PHPCSUtils
ln -s ../PHPCSExtra/Universal Universal
ln -s ../PHPCSExtra/NormalizedArrays NormalizedArrays
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of months ago an existing `WordPress` sniff was replaced with a more robust `Universal` sniff (part of the `PHPCSExtra` package).

Commit: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards/commit/8997d689294fbf880b427873e7fa254237f3b87f

Despite the `PHPCSExtra` package being a required packed by `WordPress-Coding-Standards`, it did not automatically install for me. I believe my issue was a default `"minimum-stability": "stable"` setting which prevented PHPCSExtra (still in `alpha`) from installing.

I resolved this by installing the following packages manually.

**NOTE:** I'm using PHPCS + WPCS globally. Remove `global` if attempting to install locally for a single project.

```
composer global require phpcsstandards/phpcsutils:@alpha
composer global require phpcsstandards/phpcsextra:@alpha
```

Adding the `@alpha` flag for each package overrides your default `minimum-stability` setting.

Hope this helps!

Comment: At the time of writing, PHPCSExtra has  released its 1.0.3 version.